# Nautilus/file "executable as program" option not displayed for .jar files

Tags: nautilus, files, 22.10

Ubuntu 22.10
My son's computer does not offer the option named "executable as program" in properties when in files. (Nautilus?)

My 22.10 does.

What does it take to make Ubuntu understand that .jar can can executable?
(chmod +x works fine)

Comment: It's handled by the `binfmt` mechanism I think - the `jarwrapper` package may also be required

Comment: Unfortunately - installing jarwrapper did not fix it.